# Matlab: How to avoid artefacts in filled contour plots

Tags: matlab, pdf, vector-graphics

I am trying to export filled contour plots from Matlab as vector graphics to include in a Latex file. My current methodology is:

```
contourf(x,y,v_mag,20), axis([0,width,0,height]),daspect('manual') ;
grid off
colormap jet
h = colorbar;
caxis([0 v_lid])
h.Label.String = 'Velocity Magnitude (m/s)';
set(gcf,'renderer','painters')
export_fig('-painters', '-transparent', 'pdf', 'filename.pdf');
```

The problem with this method is that it produces artefacts (the white lines) which look like the following:
[image: Artefacts in PDFs produces from Matlab]

I understand that these white lines are the polygons defining the shaded areas which have invisible edges, and don't quite overlap [(according to here)](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#ExportShading). The problem is caused by the pdf viewer itself which tries to smooth the lines displayed on the screen [(according to here)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15388-artifacts-in-figures-exported-as-pdf-from-matlab). My problem is that most people viewing the document will not know this and will not know how to prevent the viewer doing this. So my questions is:

Is it possible to create a vector graphic of a filled contour plot from Matlab without these artefacts?

Eps produces the same problems. I have tried to use the [SVG function](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401-scalable-vector-graphics--svg--export-of-figures) but have not had any luck. I am trying to avoid using raster graphics due to the pixelation caused by zooming in. Any advice would be much appreciated.

*EDIT* - Additional info - Using Matlab v.2014b and Ghostscript v.9.15

Comment: Do these lines change when you zoom in and out in your PDF viewer?

Comment: Yes, they do change. When zooming they disappear. Once zoomed they change.

Comment: In this case, the file is correct and fine, but it is an issue with the PDF viewer in use. The effect is mainly caused by rounding differences in the renderer. It may be annoying, and require some instructions to ignore those lines.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I appreciate that it is the fault of the pdf viewer. I even know know to prevent the pdf viewer doing it. The problem is that others will not. My question is whether or not it is possible to create the vector graphic in Matlab such that the pdf viewer will not display these artefacts in the first place.

Comment: OK, my expertise is PDF, so, for the Matlab issue, I am sure someone else can help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe with my test data. Can you give a way (or share a link) to display the same data than you are trying to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extremely frustrating issue for which there seems to be no solution (or even, few attempts at a solution), and it has been many years now. In summary, Matlab cannot cope with outputting artefact-free contour or surface plots (anything with complicated meshes or transparencies).

I can suggest a simple workaround that will work in most cases, where the colours or details of the underlying contour plot do not need to be preserved perfectly.

1. Output a version of the figure without lines in png format with high enough resolution.
2. Output a version of the figure without colours in pdf format. This should be free of any artefacts. If your figure it complicated and has many transparencies, you may need to output multiple versions building up the 'levels'.
3. Use Adobe Illustrator (or some equivalent) to perform a vectorized trace of the raster image. You may lose some detail here, but for simple contour plots with limited details, it will be converted easily to vectorized form.
4. Overlay the two images within Illustrator. Output in vector format.

This also allows you to use things like Illustrator's ability to compress pdfs.

If you don't want to toy with vectorizing the raster output, you can also simply replace steps 3-4 and combine a raster colour image with a vectorized line image. This would work well for complicated contour plots giving you crisp lines, but the ability to compress the underlying colours.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, MatLab 2013b doesn't have this problem. Furthermore the files it produces has much less volume. That is because MatLab 2013b composes vectorized image of big overlapping figures, while MatLab 2014b makes that awful meshing.

[image]

Here the first file was got with 2013b and the second with MatLab 2014b (I highlighted one of the polygons with red stroke to show the difference). The volumes differ in approximately 22 times (38 Kb vs. 844 Kb).

So it is not the viewer problem, it's how the image is exported from MatLab.

The issue is also discussed here [Triangular split patches with painters renderer in MATLAB 2014b and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870613/triangular-split-patches-with-painters-renderer-in-matlab-2014b-and-above/31560061#31560061), but still no direct solution.