# Triangular split patches with painters renderer in MATLAB 2014b and above

Tags: matlab, pdf, matlab-hg2

MATLABs new graphics engine, HG2, fails to properly print patches using the painters renderer:

```
hist(randn(1,1000)); 
colorbar('Location','SouthOutside');
print('test.pdf','-dpdf');
```

The resulting patches, whether generated by `hist` or `colorbar`, have triangular splits:

[image: Triangular splits in patches]

The issue has been discussed on MATLAB Central [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15388-artifacts-in-figures-exported-as-pdf-from-matlab) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/162257-problem-with-patch-graphics-in-2014b-splits-in-two-along-diagonal), where it was suggested that disabling the "smooth line art" option in the pdf-viewer should solve it. This conceals the problem in some readers (e.g. in Adobe Reader but not in Apple Preview), but it is hardly a solution to ask collaborators and readers to use a specific pdf-viewer with non-default settings for graphics to appear correctly. Looking at the resulting file in Inkscape, it is clear that the split is present in the output vector graphics. Here, I moved one half of the colorbar, proving that it is in fact split in half, and not just misinterpreted by the pdf-viewer:

[image]

The problem is not present using the OpenGL renderer (`print('test.pdf','-opengl')`, but then the output is not vectorized). The problem persists in MATLAB 2015a.

Is there a way to export artifact-free vector graphics in MATLAB 2014b or later?

Comment: The only solution I've found so far is to post-process, e.g. in Adobe Illustrator. For The color bar it helps to just remove the clipping mask. For the histogram, you have to select all the triangles (Through select same appearance) and add a thin outline stroke. It doesn't help that MATLAB does not export the triangles as closed paths, so potentially you have to close each path manually to make this work. This, of course, is only feasible for not too complex final figures...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a questionable work-around until the actual problem is solved:

The diagonal lines are simply the empty space between the triangles, so what we are seeing is the white space behind the patches peek through. **Silly idea:
Let's fill that space with matching colors instead of white.**

To do so, we'll copy all objects and offset the new ones by just a tiiiiny bit.

**Code:**

```
hist(randn(1,1000));
colorbar('Location','SouthOutside');
print('test.pdf','-dpdf');               %// print original for comparison

f1 = gcf;
g  = get(f1,'children');
n  = length(g);
copyobj(g,f1);                           %// copy all figure children
```

The copied objects are now the first `n` elements in the `2*n` `f1.Children` array. They are exactly *on top* of the old objects.

```
g=get(f1,'children');
for i=1:n;
    if strcmpi(g(i).Type,'axes');
        set(g(i),'color','none','position',g(i).Position+[0.0001 0 0 0]);
        set(g(i+n),'position',g(i+n).Position);                            %// important!
    end;
end;
print('test2.pdf','-dpdf');
```

**Explanation:**

`g  = get(f1,'children');` gets all axes, colorbars, etc., within the current figure.

`colorbar` objects are linked to an axes, which is why we'll only have to move the `axes` type children.

Setting the `color` to `none` makes the background of the new axes transparent (since they are on top of the old ones).

`g(i).Position+[0.0001 0 0 0]` shifts the new axes by 0.0001 normalized units to the right.

`set(g(i+n),'position',g(i+n).Position);` This line seems unnecessary, but the last image below shows what happens when printing if you don't include it.

Depending on the types of graphics objects you have plotted, you may need to tweak this to fit your own needs, but this code should work if you have *only colorbar and axes objects*.

**Original:**

[image: original]

**With hack:**

[image]

**Without `%// important!` line:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In R2015b, `histogram` seemed to not show the white lines, but `fill` did.

For simple plots just paste the data again:

```
x = 0:pi/100:pi;
y = sin(x);
f = fill(x,y,'r');
hold on;
f2 = fill(x,y,'r'); %// Worked like magic
```

If the magic fails try similar to Geoff's answer: `f2 = fill(x+0.0001,y,'r');`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Matlab you are using, you might try to use [epsclean](https://github.com/Conclusio/matlab-epsclean). It doesn’t seem to work with very recent versions of Matlab like 2017a.

Otherwise, epsclean can be run on an existing eps file (not pdf) exported with the -painters option to generate a vectorized figure, and it will rewrite (or create another file) with those white lines removed.